# How many solutions are there to a congruence like $x^2 + x + 1 \equiv 0$ mod $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}/_{p}\mathbb{Z}$ where $p$ is an odd prime number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can I find the number of solutions to a congruence like $x^2 + x + 1 \equiv 0$ mod $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}/_{p}\mathbb{Z}$ where $p$ is an odd prime number?

Why is that the case?

Comment: Why is what the case?

Comment: Why is it the case that that is the number of solutions? is what I meant to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no solution if $p=2$, so we can take $p$ to be an odd prime. The congruence is equivalent to $4x^2+4x+4\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, or equivalently to $(2x+1)^2\equiv -3\pmod{p}$.

The congruence $y^2\equiv -3\pmod{p}$ has either $0$ solutions or $2$ solutions. To determine the primes $p$ for which there are $2$, calculate the Legendre symbol $(-3/p)$ in the usual way.

**Remark:** Essentially the same idea works for any quadratic congruence modulo an odd prime. Consider the congruence $ax^2+bx+c\equiv 0$, where $p$ does not divide $a$. The congruence is equivalent to $4a^2x^2+4abx+4ac\equiv 0\pmod{p}$, which can be rewritten as $(2ax+b)^2\equiv b^2-4ac\pmod{p}$.

If $b^2-4ac\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ there is a unique solution. Otherwise, there are $2$ solutions if $b^2-4ac$ is a quadratic residue of $p$, and $0$ if $b^2-4ac$ is a quadratic non-residue of $p$.

Comment: Really a perfect answer to what I was asking. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. If you have a further question, I can answer it by adding material or in a comment.

Comment: I have a quick question yes.  If for a positive odd integer $n$ and an integer $k$, the Jacobi symbol ($\frac{k}{n}$) is $1$, then I think it does not follow that $k$ is a square in $\mathbb{Z}/_n\mathbb{Z}$. But if the Jacobi symbol is $-1$, then it DOES follow that $k$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Z}/_n\mathbb{Z}$.  Are these statements correct?

Comment: Yes, that's true. If for example $n=pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, we could have $(k/(pq))=1$ because $(k/p)$ and $(k/q)$ are both $-1$, so $k$ is NR modulo $p$ and therefore mod $n$. But if $(k/(p_1\cdots p_t))=-1$, then at least one of the $k/p_i$ is $-1$, so $k$ is NR modulo $n$.